# jQuery and datatables: pass an array to server-side datasource

Tags: jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc-3, datatables

I have a datatable which uses a server side datasource like this:

```
    $('.taskTable').dataTable({
       "bServerSide": true,
       "bProcessing": false,
       "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
          ...
          aoData.push({ "name": "groupIDs", "value": $("#groupIDs").val() });
          ...
          $.ajax({
             'dataType': 'json',
             'type': 'post',
             'url': "@Url.Action(MVC.Tasks.Tasks.DataTable())",
             'data': aoData
          });
      }
   });
```

Problem is, `$("#groupIDs").val()` doesn't format the values so they bind with my model (.NET MVC3). .NET wants to see something like `groupIDs[0]=23&groupIDs[1]=42&...` but instead it is sending it as `groupIDs=[23,42,...]`. How can I get datatables to send it in the right format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. Rather than struggling with getting datatables to auto format it how I wanted, I decided to manually input the values as separate parameters.

```
"fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
   var groupIDs = $("#groupIDs").val()
   if (groupIDs != null) {
      for (x = 0; x < groupIDs.length; x++) {
         aoData.push({ "name": "groupIDs[" + x + "]", "value": groupIDs[x] });
      }
   }
   ... // more code
}
```

Works great. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

groups 23, 42, .... is the equivalent of an array, now I don't know much about .net, however I am sure just like PHP it has a for, while, foreach equivalent of which on your backend you would loop over this array and do with it as you wanted to otherwise.

In this case your example `groupdIDs=[23,42]` on the back end you would do something like

(note this is PHP I apologize for it not being .net)

```
foreach($_POST['groupIDs'] as $groupid)
{
   echo $groupid."<br>";
}
```

or

```
for($i=0;$i < count($_POST['groupIDs']);$i++)
{
    echo $_POST['groupIDs'][$i]."<br>";
}
```

or

```
echo $_POST['groupIDs'][0]."<br>";
echo $_POST['groupIDs'][1]."<br>";
```

Comment: This is all javascript on the client, not server side. Thanks though.